# Debug apk is working fine but signed APK is not working properly

Tags: android, apk, signed

We have developed an application
In debug mode all the functionalities are working fine but when i try to generate Release mode apk some of the functionalities are not working properly.

I have created .jks file and followed all the steps that are needed to generate singed APK but the build is not working properly. Even i have created a new .jks file and tried but the issue is not fixed.

Can you anyone suggest me and give me the solution.

Comment: Please Check your proguard if it is configured correctly

Comment: What functionality is not working, is functionality related to Facebook, firebase, or notification?

Answer (score 2):

if your project uses Library jar  then both opion should be enable 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@mzeus.bolt the right check your build.gradle for main module (app by default), see buildTypes and signingConfigs if minifyEnabled or useProguard you should check proguard rules. For most third party libraries you can find requesred proguard rules at their github pages.

Answer (score 0):

please set the destination path like -->
D:\android or D:\examples , D:\examples\abcd\demo1
not like -->
D:\android test1\demo1 or D:\android demo1\test\demo1
(Note: every folder name like single name which folder used in path location)

[Firsr screen short fro generate apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sywx2.png)

[image: Second Screenshot for set destination Sign APK Path(Note: Note change destiation path )]

Comment: try to give different possible solution do not repeat given answer